# Ajax não envia dados para o PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

tenho o seguinte código em Ajax:

```
<script>
    $('#enviar').click(function() {   
        let dados
        let filtros = document.getElementsByName('filtro[]');
        let filtrosvalidos = [];
        filtros.forEach(function(elemento, index){
            if(elemento.checked){
                filtrosvalidos.push(elemento.value)
            }
        })
        let pesquisa = document.getElementById('pesquisa').value
        let pesquisa2 = document.getElementById('pesquisa2').options[document.getElementById('pesquisa2').selectedIndex].value
        let horaatual = document.getElementById('horaatual').value
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "pesquisar.php",
            crossDomain: true,      
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //dataType: 'json',       
            data:{
                    filtro: JSON.stringify(filtrosvalidos),
                    pesquisa: JSON.stringify(pesquisa),
                    pesquisa2: JSON.stringify(pesquisa2),
                    horaatual: JSON.stringify(horaatual),
            },
            success : function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // dados = JSON.parse(responseData)
                // processarDados(dados)
                console.log(responseData);
            }
});
```

});

E no php, o seguinte código:

```
<?php

echo 'ok';
echo json_decode($_POST['filtro']);
```

?>

Entretanto, nada sai no console quando retorno o 'echo' do php para o ajax. Alguém sabe o motivo?

Comment: `print_r(json_decode($_POST['filtro']));`

Comment: Não é esse o problema, pois o json_decode retorna uma string, então eco funcionaria da mesma forma. Mas ainda sim, eu teste print_r e ele me retorna dizendo que o índice 'filtro' é indefinido. Se eu coloco echo ($POST) ele me retorna um array vazio, por isso eu disse na pergunta que desconfio que o ajax não está enviando os dados para o PHP.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução. Troquei POST por GET, tanto no código ajax como no código PHP e funcionou.